# Regex to find multiple string pattern in a multiline text

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace a string (which is an image name with digest tag) in a file with a new string. The string can exist multiple times in a file and it can have a string appended optinionally (`as *`)

As an example:

```
FROM node:16.6.0-alpine3.14@sha256:e97343440257d8ce09817bcb27b509ff85e156bee1cee7b95ef16fa0065552f3 as build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./package*.json ./
RUN npm install 

FROM node:16.6.0-alpine3.14@sha256:e97343440257d8ce09817bcb27b509ff85e156bee1cee7b95ef16fa0065552f3
RUN apk add dumb-init
RUN npm install
```

The string `16.6.0-alpine3.14@sha256:e97343440257d8ce09817bcb27b509ff85e156bee1cee7b95ef16fa0065552f3` should be replaced.

I started with

```
const regex = new RegExp(/^(.*)$/, 'm')
const formatted = fileData.replace(regex, 'FROM node:' + newImage)
```

to replace the first string, which is always the first line.

But this way it is not working, as there could be multiple strings to replace (which I would not get) and in the example `as build` gets lost.

So I have to do a regex for the string between `FROM node:` and  `as` or to the end of the line. Something like

```
const regex = new RegExp(/^FROM node:(.*)( as.*)?$/, 'm')
```

The string itself has always the version number, dash, alpine version, @ and the SHA256 digest. I'm not sure if the SHA256 digest has always the same length. So in this case it should be possible to search for the correct formatted string, right?

Comment: Use the `/g` modifier in your regex.  By the way, what is the replacement?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The replacement is just a new string in the same format: a new version of the image with a new digest

Comment: I'm fairly certain multiple replacements in regex has been answered before on SO, is the question more centered around how to get the correct regex pattern for your specific case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the `/g` global modifier in the regex replacement.  I used a fairly generic regex pattern below, which happens to work well for the data you did show us.  You might have to tighten it up a bit for your actual full data set.

```js
var input = `FROM node:16.6.0-alpine3.14@sha256:e97343440257d8ce09817bcb27b509ff85e156bee1cee7b95ef16fa0065552f3 as build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./package*.json ./
RUN npm install 

FROM node:16.6.0-alpine3.14@sha256:e97343440257d8ce09817bcb27b509ff85e156bee1cee7b95ef16fa0065552f3
RUN apk add dumb-init
RUN npm install`;

var output = input.replace(/FROM node:.*?@\S+/g, "FROM node: <replacement>");
console.log(output);
```

Comment: It's working, but I need a bit explanation to understand it correctly. `\S+` means a single space, right? But shouldn't it be optional, as there could be just line end? The `?` makes the `@` optional?

Comment: @user3142695 `\S+` means one or more of any character which is _not_ whitespace (i.e. space, tab, CRLF, etc.)  `.*?` is called a _lazy_ dot, it means match anything up until the _nearest_ `@` character.  As mentioned in my answer, you might want to improve upon my regex pattern for best results.